# How to make a view on a TableView controller cover the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view

I have a view in a view controller with a custom background, and a navbar that is clear. the problem is that when I add the navbar to this table view controller, the view doesn't cover the back nav bar, so the nav bar looks black. How can I make the view to cover also the nav bar?

This is what happens In the table view controller, as you can see the view ends when the nav bar starts
[image: This is what happens In the table view controller, as you can see the view ends where the nav bar starts]

And this is how I want the nav bar to look like; this doesn't happen when a view controller is embeded in the nav bar, it only happens in a table view controller
[image: And this is what I want to happen, this dosn't happen when a view controller is embeded in the nav bar, it only happens in the table view controller]

Comment: You create top tableview constraint to topLayout or topSuperview?

Comment: no, this table view controller is a static table view controller, and i doesn't have any constraint in this TVC

Comment: Is `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` set to true?

Comment: I already kind of solve the problem. The problem was  that my background is a video and I was getting the frame by getting my self.view.layer.bounds, but for some reason this wasn' t drawing the height correctly but only in the table view controller, in the view controller it worked perfectly, what I made was playing with the origin Y value of the cgrect like this until i find that value that makes the background draw correctly let y = self.view.bounds.origin.y - 70. I don' t why this happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your view's top constraint is pinned to the nav bar rather than the top of the view. Just change the top of the table view to be pinned to the top of the screen instead of the bottom of the nav bar.

Comment: this table view controller is a static table view controller, and i doesn't have any constraint in this TVC

Comment: I recommend adding a basic UIViewController in the storyboard and then adding the table view. This gives you more options on how you want to place the table view. Once you do that it is easy to change the top constraint on the table view.